# Can two people play Grand Theft Auto 5 at the same time?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

Like two people, two controllers, one console on splitscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't. GTA V is a one-player game, but if you both own the game you could play GTA Online together.